Check string in one cell and if another cell is greater than 0 then
I have two worksheets, first "LoC" in column "A" I have names, I would like to update column "M" and add "YES" if below conditions were met.

If in worksheet "APME" in column "L" in string have name from column "A" of tab "LoC" and if in column "J" of tab "APME" I have amount.

Here is my code, I don't know where I made a mistake. Can anyone help me?
Sub InString_two_conditions()
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell_2 As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim criteria1 As Range

LastRowLoC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LoC").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowAPME = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("APME").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowLoC

Set criteria1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LoC").Cells(i, 1)
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("APME").Range("L3:L" & LastRowAPME)
        If InStr(UCase(cell.Value), UCase(criteria1)) > 0 And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value <> 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LoC").Cells(i, 13) = "Yes"
        End If
    Next cell

    Next i
    
End Sub 

I don't know where I made a mistake in my code. Can anyone help me?

You calculate the last row for sheet AMPE using column A (=1), and as this column is empty (except for the header row), LastRowAPME is 1.

Both tables in worksheets are dynamic, and if I'm checking string i have to avoid issue with size of letters

This is not the case, in my original files i have data in column A of tab "APME"

Okay, in that case you should use the debugger and check where you code behaves different than expected. Are the values for LastRowLoC and LastRowAPME correct?  Is the Instr-function finding the criteria1 string?

Both LastRows are ok, part instring should be ok because when I have used code without this part "And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value <> 0" columns were described correctly. Can anyone help me find problem?

Just out of curiosity: why not use a formula?

A VBA Lookup: 2 Criteria Lookup
A Quick Fix
Sub InString_two_conditions()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim wsAPME As Worksheet: Set wsAPME = wb.Sheets("APME")
    Dim LastRowAPME As Long:
    LastRowAPME = wsAPME.Cells(wsAPME.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rgAPME As Range: Set rgAPME = wsAPME.Range("L3:L" & LastRowAPME)

    Dim wsLoC As Worksheet: Set wsLoC = wb.Sheets("LoC")
    Dim LastRowLoC As Long:
    LastRowLoC = wsLoC.Cells(wsLoC.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim cellLoC As Range, cellAPME As Range, i As Long
        
    For i = 2 To LastRowLoC
        Set cellLoC = wsLoC.Cells(i, "A")
        For Each cellAPME In rgAPME.Cells
            If InStr(UCase(cellAPME.Value), UCase(cellLoC.Value)) > 0 _
                    And cellAPME.Offset(0, -2).Value <> 0 Then
                wsLoC.Cells(i, "M").Value = "Yes"
                Exit For ' it is found; no need to loop any more
            End If
        Next cellAPME
    Next i
    
End Sub

Safer (Educational, Still Slow)
Sub LookupColumn()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source (Read)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("APME")
    Dim sLastRow As Long:
    sLastRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Destination (Write)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("LoC")
    Dim dLastRow As Long:
    dLastRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Additional Variables
    Dim Value As Variant, sString As String, sRow As Long, dRow As Long
    Dim IsValid As Boolean
    
    ' Lookup and Write
    For dRow = 2 To dLastRow
        Value = dws.Cells(dRow, "A").Value
        IsValid = False
        If Not IsError(Value) Then ' is no error
            If Len(Value) > 0 Then ' is no blank
                sString = CStr(Value)
                IsValid = True
            End If
        End If
        If IsValid Then ' the destination lookup string is valid
            For sRow = 3 To sLastRow
                Value = sws.Cells(sRow, "L").Value
                IsValid = False
                If Not IsError(Value) Then ' is no error
                    If Len(Value) > 0 Then ' is no blank
                        If InStr(1, Value, sString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            IsValid = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                If IsValid Then ' the source lookup string is found
                    Value = sws.Cells(sRow, "J").Value
                    IsValid = False
                    If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                        If Value <> 0 Then ' is no zero
                            IsValid = True
                        End If
                    End If
                    If IsValid Then ' the source return number is valid
                        dws.Cells(dRow, "M").Value = "Yes in row " & sRow
                        Exit For ' i.e. 'Next dRow'
                    'Else ' the source return number is invalid
                    End If
                'Else ' the source lookup string is not found
                End If
            Next sRow
        'Else ' the destination lookup string is invalid
        End If
    Next dRow
        
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Column updated.", vbInformation
        
End Sub


Why programming this in VBA if you can do it with a "simple" formula, like in the following screenshot:

As you see, I have the value "XccX" and another cell, containing "XccX".
I use the XMatch() worksheet function, using "2" as a parameter (in order to use regular expressions), and I turn the XccX into *XccX* as a regular expression to look for, and indeed, it is found.
The XMatch() return value can be combined with the IsNumber() worksheet function in order to determine whether or not the entry has been found.
This second screenshot gives a more total approach:


It has to be in VBA

So? You can use VBA to write a formula inside a cell, having the same result.
